# Vba Shell call works with some programs but does not work with others

Tags: excel, vba, shell

`Shell` call works with some programs that I have but does not work with others. I am putting the most basic call here for opening an exe without any further commands

```vb
Shell "C:\Program Files\qBittorrent\qbittorrent.exe", 1 'works
Shell "C:\Program Files\AmiBroker\Broker.exe", 1 'works
Shell "C:\Program Files\CTrading\QuantShare\QuantShare.exe", 1 'Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Equis\MetaStock\MsWin.exe", 1 'same error
```

I am on the verge of giving up unless I meet a savior here!!
System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1909 OS Build 18363.476
Microsoft Excel 2013 64-bit

Comment: What happens if you do the same in a command prompt?

Comment: CMD or Windows Run, It all works

Comment: You have a funny antivirus?

Comment: I had Kaspersky that I removed and tried the macro again. Still same issue. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove `,  1`? That is optional and can be omitted.

Comment: You have more funny antiviruses other than Kaspersky?

Comment: Windows Defender which was off as Kaspersky was on. After removing Kaspersky, I haven't switched on Defender.

Comment: Andreas: Removing the last param doesn't make any difference.

Comment: There doesnt seem to be any light at the end of the tunnel!! May be a Windows issue for ever!! But still if any Savior appears, I owe him a lot...be my guest in Mumbai!!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an ugly fix, but it might help:

```
Shell "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\CTrading\QuantShare\QuantShare.exe""", 1
```

I don't have any of the programs you are having problems with, so it is a bit of a guess. If this doesn't help, the next step is `cmd /c start ...`

Comment: Thanks. This opens the CMD and the prompt for the exe opening. Though I put just the program exe with Shell to show how its not working, eventual objective is to send commands to be executed inside the target program. One example:


res = Shell("C:\Program Files\CTrading\QuantShare\QuantShare.exe TaskManager ChangeSymbol newsymbol:" & Range("A2"), 1)


This sends the content of Cell A2 as a global variable for a script inside the target program.

Comment: Though you may not have any of my programs, may be you can try various programs that you have and make a basic Shell call. May be, you may find that the Call goes for some but not for others.

Comment: Mostly, something to do with Windows whereby something in some programs no longer lets Shell calls to proceed. i rolled back recent updates to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i could use ShellExecute as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A2000")) Is Nothing Then
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
para = "TaskManager ChangeSymbol newsymbol:" & ActiveCell.Value
objShell.ShellExecute "C:\Program Files\CTrading\QuantShare\QuantShare.exe", para, "", "open", 1
Set objShell = Nothing
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Can I make ShellExecute not to open a new instance of the program and rather activate the currently open instance and pass the arguments (similar to Shell call? Also how to make ShellExecute not take focus? I want the focus to stay back in Excel.